# How to send more than one CopyPixelOperation through CopyFromScreen?

Tags: c#

I am using the managed Graphics.CopyFromScreen method to take a Bitmap screenshot of a region on the screen.

Everything is working using the CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy enum as the flag to the CopyFromScreen method... but unfortunately I need to capture layered / transparent windows that are in the region I'm trying to capture... and with only the SourceCopy enum these do not get picked up in the resulting image.  This can be solved using the CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt... but I can't find a way to do this:

```
Graphics.CopyFromScreen(left, top, 0, 0, size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy | CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt); // note the binary OR operator
```

... as this results in a "Bitwise Or is not possible on type enum" style error from Resharper - upon which I researched the error discovering that bitwise operations on enums happens on the numeric representation of the enum values and you will end up with another one of the available enum values (opposed to two of them).

Is there a way to pass two enums to this function or a similar function?  I have a preference in staying managed if possible.

---

**MSDN Documentation**

- [CopyFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx)
- [CopyPixelOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.copypixeloperation.aspx)

Comment: Please note that CopyFromScreen has a GDI handle leak, which means you should not be relying on calling this method over and over again many times in your application, or you'll eventually starve both your application and possible other applications from handles. This bug still exists in .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem compiling your code.

Comment: Lasse: I am indeed calling it over and over again... thanks for the nugget of wisdom!!  Do you know if there is a 'place' (newsletter, blog, msdn page) I can watch for a fix?  Or should I assume it will be .NET 4?

Comment: Coincoin: sorry I wasn't be very clear in my original question... it's a resharper error and on researching it I found some documentation explain why enums cannot be combined using bitwise functions as the resulting value will not equate to the two enums combined - it will instead equate to a completely different enum or it won't even match a value enum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MSDN:

> copyPixelOperation
>   Type: System.Drawing..::.CopyPixelOperation
>   **One of** the CopyPixelOperation values.

You can't combine those flags, you probably want to use `CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt` alone anyway.

Comment: I've gone down the unmanaged route given Lasse's comment about the handle leak in CopyFromScreen and also to get around the 'one of the' limitation that you picked out of the docs.

Thanks for the help.